# Angularjs ng-click does not work in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angularjs-ng-click

Using angularjs and kendo grid I am trying to call a function on the selection of a checkbox in the grid. But no matter what I do nothing happens in ng-click, not even an error is thrown. I have added console.log() at the top of the method called but nothing shows up. I have tried to add the method in a service in scope and also directly in scope.

Basically my question is how to use ng-click on a checkbox in a kendo grid cell template?

Here is grid binding code:

```
var cols = this.GetGridColumns(uiConfig.GridColumns);

var grid = $("#kGrid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
   serverPaging: true,
   serverSorting: true,
   schema: {
         data: "data",
         total: "total",
         model: {
         id: "relatedEntityID"
         }
   },
   pageSize: 10,
   transport: {
   read: function(options) {
          /* read from service */
       }
     }
   },
   columns: cols, 
   scrollable: false,
   pageable: { "refresh": true, "pageSizes": true },
   sortable: true,
   filterable: true,
   selectable: "multiple",
   change: () => this.onChange()
});
```

and here is the definition of

```
GetGridColumns(columns: Array<servicePath.SLF.solutionEngine.Model.Admin.GridColumn>): any
    {
        var colHeader = new Array();

        colHeader.push({
            template: '<input type="checkbox" id="cbItem" class="checkbox" ng-click="genericServices.selectRow(\'kGrid\', $event)" />',

            headerTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" id="check-all" ng-click="genericServices.ToggleCheckAllInGrid(\'#kGrid\', $event)" />',
            width: '30px'});

        var column = new servicePath.SLF.solutionEngine.Model.CMs.GridColumnCM();

        for (var j=0 ; j < columns.length; j++)
        {
            column = new servicePath.SLF.solutionEngine.Model.CMs.GridColumnCM();

            column.Field = columns[j].BindingName;
            column.Title = columns[j].BindingName;
            column.ColumnType = columns[j].GridColumnType;
            column.HorizontalAlignment = columns[j].HorizontalAlignment;
            column.LocalizedName = columns[j].LocalizedLabel;

            colHeader.push({ title: column.Name, field: columns[j].BindingName, template: column.Template } );
        }

        return colHeader;
    }
```

In above code genericServices.ToggleCheckAllInGrid in header template is working perfectly fine.

This is definition of genericServices.

```
this.selectRow = function (gridId: string, e: any): void {
            gridId = '#' + gridId;
            console.log(gridId);

            var elem = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
            var row = elem.closest("tr");
            var checked = elem.prop('checked');

            if (checked) {
                //-select the row
                row.addClass("k-state-selected");
            } else {
                //-remove selection
                row.removeClass("k-state-selected");
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the angular bootstrap run before the rows added to the grid (to the DOM).

If so, you have to call angular bootstrap manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the onclick event on kendo grid header using below code:

```
$('body ').on('click','.grid .k-header',function(e){

 //write your logic..
});
```

In kendo grid you cannot use ng-click or onClick events. Only href will work.

Comment: that is what I am doing right now but this seems more like a hack.

Comment: this is what I actually ended up doing but I am not satisfied with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

What if you'd use a directive to respond to the click? http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive `ng-click` is quite jQuery-like.

Comment: I know how to create directives but how would I do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Something like:
angular.module('modulename').directive('k-header',[],function() { return { restrict: 'C', link: function($scope,$el,$attr) { $el.on('click', function(ev) { /* ... logic ... */ }); } }; }); where restrict: 'C' listens on class names and the link function returns the element. This way, you're in Angular scope and Angular will fire when needed.